# select list option go on top of control

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I don't know why but for some reason even when I use the most plained example, either regular HTML or bootstrap, the option list goes on top of the select control itself.
No idea why.
Help someone?

My code looks like this

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
     <select class="custom-select" id="sel1">
        #foreach( $state in $stateList )
        <option value="$state">$state</option>
        #end
     </select>
  </div>
</form>



<select class="custom-select">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="vw">VW</option>
    <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Both example gives back the same visual problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oezsx.jpg)

Comment: What's your CSS for the .custom-select?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to look like a lot. But, here is an example with your code (only one select though). It isn't really a bootstrap solution its from W3c like your example.

You can try this:

```js
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/* Look for any elements with the class "custom-select": */
x = document.getElementsByClassName("test-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item: */
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /* For each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list: */
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /* For each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item: */
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /* When an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item: */
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /* When the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box: */
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /* A function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box: */
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

/* If the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes: */
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
/* The container must be positioned relative: */
.test-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.test-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element: */
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

/* Style the arrow inside the select element: */
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active): */
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

/* style the items (options), including the selected item: */
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Style items (options): */
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

/* Hide the items when the select box is closed: */
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="test-select">
      <select class="custom-select">
        <option value="0">Select car:</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="vw">VW</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It just makes my control disapear.

Comment: I just saw it's a problem in IE. It works well in Chrome. Just not sure why and how to fix it.

Comment: I added a quick edit. If you add another option that has no real value you can get around the first option in the list disappearing.

Comment: Again..It works well in Chrome... the example I posted. It's IE that gives the problem. Go to w3schools in IE 11 (for example) and look how the select list looks like. It's an issue with the browser.

Comment: I used your example and it does help, BUT... the arrow of the select list is getting overriden because of the position relative the custom-select has. Do you know how to fix it?